# Why does hot water and cold water makes different sounds while filling a bucket from a tap

Tags: thermodynamics, acoustics

When I fill hot water in a bucket while bathing, there is a difference in the noise it makes compared to cold water. Is there any Relation between temperature of water and sound it makes during falling in to a bucket.

[image]

Comment: Does the sound change as the water in the hot-water pipe warms up from cold to hot?

Comment: I don't know, but the density of the water is going to be slightly different, and depending on what heated it, the amount of dissolved gas will be different, and one or the other may also contain tiny bubbles of gas that the other does not.

Comment: I believe it's cause the different speed of sound due to the temperature differences (in the water as well as in the air layer above the water) and due to the air composition (attenuation on the small vapor particles).

Comment: If hot and cold water don't have the same pressure then they come at different speed. 
Maybe also, with hot water the plastic bucket is softer and would make different sound harmonics.

Comment: Hot water is coming from over head solar tank and cold water from another tank of same height.pressure is same for both the liquids.
Yes, i used a plastic bucket and will try with an aluminium bucket and check again.

Comment: I filled hot and cold water in an aluminium bucket to compare the sound it makes,they are distinctively different.means, bucket material is not the reason.

Comment: I can hear how hot the water is pouring from an electric kettle in to a heavy mug. The mug is not making noise, the water itself sounds clearly different when nearly boiling, hot, lukewarm and cold. I think that most people have to be familiar with this experience. If not, try it now.